# Which 80s fantasy series had sword masters with different styles teaming up?

Tags: story-identification

It had different sword masters and styles, all coming together to fight a greater evil. The styles had different names and if I recall correctly the masters were more like dancers. I wish I had more to offer.

I 'think' it had a northern feel to it. Like Norse almost.

Comment: Was it in English?  Was it a cartoon or live action? Any memorable scenes or music?

Answer (score 5):

Gotta throw out the Sword-Dancer series by Jennifer Roberson.

[http://www.amazon.com/Sword-Dancer-Tiger-Del-Jennifer-Roberson/dp/0886773768](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0886773768)

Hits some of your key elements- sword dancing, protagonist is a Northern Swordswoman "born of ice and storm", multiple sword dancing masters.

Answer (score 2):

I keep checking back to see if there are more details. Is it a written work? if so, I've got a possibility in mind, based on little more then a hunch.
First, I don't think I've read the book I'm suggesting, nor can I find a decent online summary. BUT, how about *"A Gathering of Heroes"* by [Paul Edwin Zimmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Edwin_Zimmer)? It is a prequel to his earlier *Dark Border* books, *"The Lost Prince"* and *"King Chondros' Ride"*. Those books stand out for me due to the incredibly detailed and (to me) sometimes tedious description of sword fighting.

Istvan the Archer (don't ask), is a world renowned swordsman, a master of the three swords school of fighting, and bears a powerful *Hastur* blade.

However, the setting is more otherworldly-fantasy-medieval with no explicit 'Norse' elements.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but it sounds like it could be Dave Duncan The Seventh Sword series

http://www.baenebooks.com/c-84-the-seventh-sword-by-dave-duncan.aspx

The only thing that might not work is the different styles of fighting... but it could be the many rules they have a swordsman must know to advance